# How to Find in Excel the total count of how many times each banks increase interest rate?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have dataset of all the interest rate.

I want to find the formula for Excel, I want to know total count of How many times each banks increase interest rate in a one-month periods, how many times each banks decrease interest rate in a one-month periods, how many times each banks kept interest rate same in a one-month periods. I have data is of 1 month period.

I have tried different formula but it's coming ERROR or wrong number

This is the current column setup:

```
Column A = Provider (Bank Name) 
Column B = Product Name 
Column C = Market Name 
Column D = 1/11/2022 (Interest Rate Data) 
Column E = 2/11/2022 (Interest Rate Data) 
Column F = 3/11/2022 (Interest Rate Data) 
Column G = 4/11/2022 (Interest Rate Data) 
Column H = 5/11/2022 (Interest Rate Data) 
Column I = 6/11/2022 (Interest Rate Data) 
Column J = 7/11/2022 (Interest Rate Data) 
Column K = 8/11/2022 (Interest Rate Data) 
Column L = 9/11/2022 (Interest Rate Data) 
Column M = 10/11/2022 (Interest Rate Data)
Column N = 11/11/2022 (Interest Rate Data) 
Column O = 12/11/2022 (Interest Rate Data) 
Column P = 13/11/2022 (Interest Rate Data) 
Column Q = 14/11/2022 (Interest Rate Data) 
Column R = 15/11/2022 (Interest Rate Data) 
Column S = 16/11/2022 (Interest Rate Data) 
Column T = 17/11/2022 (Interest Rate Data) 
Column U = 18/11/2022 (Interest Rate Data) 
Column V = 19/11/2022 (Interest Rate Data) 
Column W = 20/11/2022 (Interest Rate Data) 
Column X = 21/11/2022 (Interest Rate Data) 
Column Y = 22/11/2022 (Interest Rate Data) 
Column Z = 23/11/2022 (Interest Rate Data)
```

These are the columns with values I'd like to calculate:

```
Column AH = Total Increase (Need Excel formula to find this) 
Column AI = Total Decrease (Need Excel formula to find this) 
Column AJ = Total No Changes (Need Excel formula to find this)
```

Comment: This below column formula I am trying to find if anyone can help me. Thanks in advance.

Column AH = Total Increase (Need Excel formula to find this)
Column AI = Total Decrease (Need Excel formula to find this)
Column AJ = Total No Changes (Need Excel formula to find this)

Comment: My data column is structure as following

Column A = Provider (Bank Name)
Column B = Product Name
Column C = Market Name
Column D = 1/11/2022 (Interest Rate Data)
Column E = 2/11/2022 (Interest Rate Data)
Column F = 3/11/2022 (Interest Rate Data)
Column G = 4/11/2022 (Interest Rate Data)
Column H = 5/11/2022 (Interest Rate Data)
Column I = 6/11/2022 (Interest Rate Data)
Column J = 7/11/2022 (Interest Rate Data)
Column K = 8/11/2022 (Interest Rate Data)
Column L = 9/11/2022 (Interest Rate Data)
Column M = 10/11/2022 (Interest Rate Data

Comment: Column N = 11/11/2022 (Interest Rate Data)
Column O = 12/11/2022 (Interest Rate Data)
Column P = 13/11/2022 (Interest Rate Data)
Column Q = 14/11/2022 (Interest Rate Data)
Column R = 15/11/2022 (Interest Rate Data)
Column S = 16/11/2022 (Interest Rate Data)
Column T = 17/11/2022 (Interest Rate Data)
Column U = 18/11/2022 (Interest Rate Data)
Column V = 19/11/2022 (Interest Rate Data)
Column W = 20/11/2022 (Interest Rate Data)
Column X = 21/11/2022 (Interest Rate Data)
Column Y = 22/11/2022 (Interest Rate Data)
Column Z = 23/11/2022 (Interest Rate Data)

Comment: Please add your data to the question, not the comments. Once it is added it should be deleted from comments. As you can see it is largely unreadable there.

Answer (score 1):

This will count how many times the rate changed from the previous day.

For cell AH2 - How many times rate increased:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(E2:Z2>D2:Y2))
```

For cell AI2 - How many times rate decreased:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(E2:Z2<D2:Y2))
```

For cell AJ2 - How many times rate did not change:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(E2:Z2=D2:Y2))
```

Answer (score 1):

### Increase/Decrease (Excel Formula)

[image]

**Whole Range**

```
=LET(d,D2:AG5,
    DROP(REDUCE("",SEQUENCE(ROWS(d)),LAMBDA(rr,r,
        LET(td,TOCOL(INDEX(d,r),1),o,DROP(td,-1),t,DROP(td,1),
VSTACK(rr,HSTACK(SUM(--(o<t)),SUM(--(o>t)),SUM(--(o=t))))))),1))
```

**Single Row**

```
=LET(d,D2:AG2,
    td,TOCOL(d,1),
    o,DROP(td,-1),t,DROP(td,1),
HSTACK(SUM(--(o<t)),SUM(--(o>t)),SUM(--(o=t))))
```

Answer (score 0):

For Column AH (Total Increase):

```
=COUNTIF(D2:Z2,"<"&D2)+COUNTIF(D2:Z2,">"&D1)-COUNTIF(D2:Z2,"="&D1)
```

For Column AI (Total Decrease):

```
=COUNTIF(D2:Z2,"<"&D1)+COUNTIF(D2:Z2,">"&D2)-COUNTIF(D2:Z2,"="&D1)
```

For Column AJ (Total No Changes):

```
=COUNTIF(D2:Z2,"="&D1)
```